# how to internationalize preg_replace (windows vs. Linux issues)

Tags: php, internationalization, preg-replace

If I run this code in **windows**, it produces 'I!t!rn!ti!n!liz!ti!n', but if I move it to my **linux** server, it no longer performs the replace.

```
print preg_replace('/[À-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]/', '!', 'Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn');
```

I've uploaded the doc as a binary, to be sure FTP wasn't the cause. I can read it fine on the server (no corruption of the symbols). It seems to be related to the Linux implementation of preg_replace?

Comment: Correction, I just uploaded this EXACT text to my linux box, it works great. However, if I take the same value from a post variable, it produces I!�t!�rn!�ti!�n!�liz!�ti!�n.

Comment: "I've uploaded the doc as a binary, to be sure FTP wasn't the cause." - Actually, there is no good reason to use ASCII mode unless you use old-school CGI scripts which **require** a certain linebreak format. So better stay with using BINARY mode even though it didn't change anything in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely locale related. But you should have the `/u` unicode modifier in the regex nevertheless. - And might the Windows version of libPCRE enables that per default?

Comment: The /u modifier causes an error message: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 2 in D:\xampp\htdocs\web\test.php on line 2

Comment: @Kato: Then investigage further. Use `recode` to verify the charset. Might even be UTF-16 or UCS2 eventually?? Do you use Asian charsets normally? (There is a browser setting for that in IE, which would explain your $_POST values.)

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to get rid of all non-ascii characters better provide a negated list of valid charaters, i.e. something like `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` (might have to add some symbols if you want them, too) instead of `[ä-öß€AndMuchMoreStuff]`

Comment: Sadly, this would also get rid of spaces, punctuation, etc. The objective is to create an accurate word count, similar to how word processors and editors count words, which is a very tricky business. PHP, for instance, counts Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn as 8 words, because of the symbols.